# React can't resolve relative path

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm having an issue with throwing me a `Module not found` error when specifying a folder, rather than an exact file path.

For example:

```
src
 - containers
   - Navigation
     - Navigation.js
 - pages
   - index.js
```

```
Navigation.js

import React from "react"
import './Navigation.min.css'

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="navigation">
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

```
index.js

import React from "react"
import Navigation from '../containers/Navigation'

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Navigation />
  </div>
)
```

Attempting to import Navigation throws `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/Navigation'`, but when I specify `import Navigation from '../containers/Navigation/Navigation.js`, it does work.

I can't seem to get it to work without the explicit file name.

Comment: You have to rename `Navigation.js` to `index.js`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix your import path

```
// the correct import path depending on your hierarchy 
import Navigation from '../../containers/Navigation'
```

" ../" is used to one folder up in the folder tree.

the

```
// will not work because your now in the Navigation folder
import "../container/Navigation "

import "../container/Navigation/Navigation" // will work becuase now you are pointing to a file, and you can omit the extenstion
```